# How to exclude certain paths in Hudson using regular expression

Tags: regex, jenkins, hudson

We use Hudson and like to exclude certain paths from the code checkout source using regular expression.

Paths to exclude:

```
src/abc/def/efg/z.h
src/abc/def/m.h
src/abc/def/efg/kvt/y.h
```

We tried but it doesn't seem to work

```
(?!=src\/abc\/def\/efg\/z\.h|src\/abc\/def\/m\.h|src\/abc\/def\/efg\/kvt\/y\.h).*
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
src\/(?!abc\/def\/efg\/z\.h|abc\/def\/m\.h|abc\/def\/efg\/kvt\/y\.h).*\.*
```

Comment: Just FYI, your answer would be a lot more useful (and thus more likely to be upvoted) if you explained how the regex worked.